# static const int as map subscript

Tags: c++

I ran into a strange issue.
Considering this example:

```
class Foo
{
  static const int Bar = 5;

public:
  Foo()
  {
    _map[Bar] = "some characters";
  }

  ~Foo() {}

private:
  std::map<int, std::string> _map;
};

int main()
{
  Foo a;

  return (0);
}
```

I get this error (compiling with g++ 4.7.2):

```
/tmp/ccLy806T.o: In function `Foo::Foo()':
Main.cpp:(.text._ZN3FooC2Ev[_ZN3FooC5Ev]+0x1e): undefined reference to `Foo::Bar'
```

Now, if I make a static_cast on Bar, it works:

```
Foo()
{
  int i = Bar; //works
  _map[static_cast<int>(Bar)] = "some characters"; //works
}
```

This error only appears when using `Bar` as map subscript in the constructor. Writing `_map[Bar] = "some characters";` in an other function in the Foo class doesn't produce any error.

That's really strange for me, but I expect that someone here has an answer.

So, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: write const int Foo::Bar = 5; before your main, but not in the class ;)

Comment: Similarly, `_map[+Bar]` works. The unary `+` invokes an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (and an integral promotion). This creates a temporary, which can be used without ord-using `Bar`.

Comment: "This error only appears when using Bar as map subscript in the constructor." [Not on all compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e045e49b06f7a44). Note this rule in the Standard (ODR) does not require any diagnostic if violated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `map::operator[]` takes its key as a `int const&`. It wants the address of the thing you're passing into it. When you do:

```
_map[static_cast<int>(Bar)]
```

you're creating a temporary, and passing in the address to that temporary, which is fine. But when you're doing:

```
_map[Bar]
```

`Bar` doesn't actually have memory storage. You need to provide it via:

```
class Foo {
    ....
};

const int Foo::Bar;
```

Comment: In terms of the Standard, `Foo::Bar` is not *odr-used* in `static_cast<int>(Bar)` because `Bar` can appear in a constant expression and there's an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied in the `static_cast`.  However, `Bar` binds directly to `const int&`, therefore no lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied - this is an odr-use, which requires a definition for `Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following at the top level to allocate storage for `Foo::Bar`:

```
const int Foo::Bar;
```